# Encrypt user home directory and keep running cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

On ubuntu I used ecryptfs to encrypt the home of the user.

I need to run some cronjobs and that jobs need to access some data that reside on the home of the user. I would like to have an external process that can mount the encrypted filesystem if a process owned by the user ask for access data on its home directory.

I was thinking on interprocess communication and I'm going to use bash.

The external process at the startup ask for the secret that will let the process to mount the encrypted filesystem, when some jobs run will ask the process to mount the home and since the external process has the secret it is able to mount the home.

Do you have any technical suggestion on how to implement that? Which kind of interprocess communication, etc.